# Is it possible to dyamically take into accounr changes in the .asoundrc file?

Tags: alsa

I'd like two switch between two different behavior for the command aplay : 
 - write to a fifo file (which is then read by snapserver ; a multiroom tool)
 - directly play music only on the local device (meaning not using a fifo file and snapserver so that delay is shortened)

To output to fifo file (located at /tmp/snapfifo) I use a dedicated .asoundrc file :

```bsh
pcm.!default {
        type plug
        slave.pcm rate48000Hz
}

pcm.rate48000Hz {
        type rate
        slave {
                pcm writeFile # Direct to the plugin which will write to a file
                format S16_LE
                rate 48000
        }
}

pcm.writeFile {
        type file
        slave.pcm null
        file "/tmp/snapfifo"
        format "raw"
}
```

with a dedicated user named btstreamer. Is it possible to dynamically change this file content and take it into account immediately ?

Comment: You could [switch with an environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17107500/11654).